# XBL control's attributes

Tags: orbeon

I have my custom XBL control, let's say :

```
<fr:my-control id="my-control-id" attr1 = "value1 value2 value3" attr2 = "aaa" ../>
```

In my XBL I have defined a handler and attr1 as `xf:select`

```
<xbl:handlers>
    <xbl:handler event="my-custom-event" phase="target">
            <xf:send submission="my-submission"/>   
 </xbl:handler>
...
<xf:select ref="@subOn">
```

And in `dialog.control.details` I have added :

```
<xf:select appearance="full" ref="if ($xforms-control/self::xf:select) then $bound-node else ()">
    <xf:label>Send submission:</xf:label>
        <xf:item>
            <xf:label>On load</xf:label>
            <xf:value>load</xf:value>
        </xf:item>
        <xf:item>
            <xf:label>On save</xf:label>
            <xf:value>save</xf:value>
        </xf:item>                              
</xf:select>
```

So I can select `load` and `save` by clicking on checkboxes in control's settings. 
Now, I would like to dispatch some event ONLY IF `attr1` contains specific word, f.e.

```
<fr:my-control id="my-control-id" attr1 = "save" attr2="...">

if(contains(normalize-space($attr1), 'save') then
<xf:dispatch ev:event="my-custom-event" observer="fr-form-model" name="my-custom-event"
  targetid="my-control-id"/>

</fr:my-control>
```

How would I do that ? 
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I would like to make myself perfectly clear, so :

**1** Inside my form generating in Form Builder there I have :

```
<fr:my-control id="my-control-id" attr1 = "save">
<xf:dispatch ev:event="my-custom-event" observer="fr-form-model" name="my-custom-event"
  targetid="my-control-id"/>
</fr:my-custom-control>
```

I placed this `<xf:dispatcher>` to catch event when user clicks on Save button in Form Runner. There is also a problem with `targetid` which I have to set always by hand to be the same as `fr:my-custom-control` but there's another issue which has its own post.

**2** Inside XBL file there i have handlers defined

`<xbl:handlers>
    <xbl:handler event="my-custom-event" phase="target">
        <xf:send submission="my-submission"/>   </xbl:handler>
</xbl:handlers>`

```
<xf:input ref="@attr1"/>
```

This handler catches `my-custom-event` and sends `my-submission` afterwards. It is done OUTSIDE xbl:template.

**3** I want to send such submission only if `attr1 = "save"`.

I tried to do this :

```
<xf:template>
<xf:var name="attr1" xbl:attr="xbl:text=attr1" >
    <xf:action ev:event="xforms-enabled xforms-value-changed">
        <xf:setvalue ref="instance('attr1')" value="$attr1"/>
    </xf:action>
</xf:var>
<xf:model>
    <xf:instance id="attr1"><value/></xf:instance>
        <xf:group ref=".[contains(normalize-space($subOn), 'save')]">
            <xf:submission id="my-submission" ..
              ..
            </xf:submission>
        </xf:group>
</xf:model>
```

That way submission is never sent.
Also I tried only adding condition to submission, like this :

```
<xf:submission id="my-submission" 
        if="contains(normalize-space($attr1), 'save')"
        ...>
</xf:submission>
```

Ironically, this way submission is always sent, no matter what `attr1` actually is.

It's not working and I have no idea why. Code seems right, but obviously there must be something wrong.

Comment: I am reading the update you did to your question, and am wondering: is the handler for `my-custom-event` running at all? What if you put there an `xf:message`; do you see the message showing? In step 1, I would put the `xf:dispatch` not inside the control, but in the `xf:model` (at the top of the form).

Answer (score 0):

From XForms, you can't access the value of another element in the DOM, so in this case, you can't access from "outside" `fr:my-control` the value of its `attr1` attribute. On the other side, the implementation of the XBL component can of course access the value of its attributes. The simplest way to do that is to declare inside the XBL control a variable, e.g.:

```
<xf:var name="attr1-attribute" xbl:attr="xbl:text=attr1"/>
```

Then, you can use, inside the control `$attr1` to refer to the value of the `attr1` attribute. Would it work for you to move that logic inside the XBL component, i.e. do the `xf:send` only if `$attr1 = 'save'`?

Comment: Thanks for response. I'd love to use this solution (I've done something similar many times in my project) but here I can't. The reason why is that I would have to add such code inside xbl:model (becuase there is where I have my submission definied), what doesn't work for some reason. Usually I put such code inside xbl:template and it works just fine.

Comment: Hey, I've created this simple example : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b41b5ee872e2cc60c246

Comment: There I have a control fr:my-name. I can set the test attribute as "test" or anything else. Now, if I publish this form and then open it in Form Runner, after clicking on save button the submission 'my-submission' will be sent. Now, I would like this submission to be sent ONLY IF test attribute is equal to "save". Could you do that ? Regards

Comment: If you need to access the value of the attribute in the model, then you can use a `<xf:setvalue>` to set it there. See for instance how it is done here: https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/xbl/orbeon/error-summary/error-summary.xbl#L183. Would this work for you?

Comment: Unforunately I keep getting emtpy value. Could you please edit my example and show me how it should be done ?

Comment: I've updated my question, I hope now you could see my mistakes there.