# Orbeon : setting targetid as a parent id

Tags: orbeon

There I have my custom XBL control :

```
<fr:my-custom-control id="" attr1="" attr2=""..>
    <xf:dispatch  targetid=".." ../>
</fr:my-custom-control>
```

I would like the `targetid` to be the parent id, f.e. after adding my custom control on the form `targetid` would be the same as the id of `fr:my-custom-control`

```
<fr:my-custom-control id="control-16-control" ..>
    <xf:dispatch targetid="control-16-control">
</fr:my-custom-control>
```

Of course, I can set this id by hand but is there a way to make it happen automatically ? I was trying

```
<xf:dispatch targetid="@fr:my-custom-control-id"/>
```

with no luck.

**UPDATE**

I was trying to avoid setting target id, like this :

```
<fr:my-custom-control id="..." ..>
   <xf:dispatch event="fr-data-save-done" observer="fr-form-model" name="my-custom-event"/>
</fr:my-custom-control>
```

but it makes that the save event is not caught at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When listening on an event, you can point to the parent node with [`ev:target="#observer"`](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-events#TOC-Specifying-the-current-observer-as-target-restriction), but you can't use the same syntax to dispatch an event to the parent node (also, the name `#observer` wouldn't make much sense in that case).

But instead of putting that logic in the generated code, couldn't it be inside the component itself, inside the `<xbl:handlers>`? This would lead to less code being generated, and allow you to change the logic after the component has been added to the form.

Comment: Thanks for response. What do you mean by putting logic inside xbl:handlers - which logic ? As I know xbl:handler must be inside XBL file and for sure xf:dispatch placed inside my form to catch save event. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Generally, I have this dispatcher because I need to catch save event in Form Runner, @ebrunchez advised me and it's working great but everytime I have to set targetid by hand.

Comment: Also, this question is kinda related to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28153693/xbl-controls-attributes ; in my first post there is an Update where I explained the whole idea - maybe it would help you to see my problem even more clearly

Comment: Instead of trying to put an event listener inside the `<fr:my-custom-control>` element that listens for `fr-data-save-done` on `fr-form-model`, and dispatches `my-custom-event` to the XBL component, you could listen for that `fr-data-save-done` on `fr-form-model` from within the XBL component. Try it. Make sure to put your code listening to the event inside the `<xbl:template>`,  and with an `xxbl:scope="outer"`. E.g. `<xf:message ev:event="fr-data-save-done" ev:observer="fr-form-model" xxbl:scope="outer">Save done!</xf:message>`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the update, and for being so persistent on this one. (It's not easy stuff!)